# Looking out for a good Visual XSLT Editor tool

Tags: xslt

Am looking out for a good Visual stylesheet designer through which i can **export my report designer directly into XSL**. I should be also able to read/**import the XSL to get back the designer**. Anyone having an idea of such tools.

Presently i am checking out the Visual Stylesheet designer from Altova. Before freezing onto it i want to check for such similar tools. Any help in this regard is deeply appreciated.

[Something similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143543/drag-and-drop-generation-of-xslt-for-displaying-xml-as-html)

Thanks a lot

Comment: What is visual stylesheet? How this is related to XSLT?

Comment: Hello 
I actually mean here a good XSLT Visual Editor.
A typical WYSIWYG tool which lets me make changes of my report on a graphical editor and gives XSL as a output.

Answer (score 0):

Have you explored Oxygen, Its worth giving a try. http://www.oxygenxml.com